# Change div that contains icon heignt

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create an effect making the arrow icon visible incresing  its height progressively on hover, and I'm trying to make a transition but I can't  set this div not visible  setting the div height to 0,

```
<div id="down-arrow-div" className="text-center down-arrow" >
     <i className="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
```

the css doesn't work

```
.down-arrow-div{
   height:0%;
}
```

I can hide the div with `visibility` but is  a binary value and the effect is not the same

Comment: try removing the percent and add overflow hidden and your css is targeting a class but your element has that as an id

Comment: Hello! :) Do you have maybe some minimal reproducible example for your case? Like codesandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using visibility, use the opacity property. Set the font height rather than the element height as the snippet below. I've added a border around the parent div so you've got something to aim for with your mouse.

```css
#down-arrow-div {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

#down-arrow-div>i {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

#down-arrow-div:hover>i {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div id="down-arrow-div" class="text-center down-arrow">
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to hide everything outside of an element, you have to apply `overflow: hidden;` to it. In this case, to the #down-arow-div. (Mind the mistake, in your example it's ".down-error-div" where it sould be "#down-error-div" (ID-selector instead of class-selector)

Answer (score 0):

As your div is having some content it will have it's children's height even if you set the height to zero.
you change the font-size of i tag and it will be fine.